# How to revert uncomitted modification?

Tags: git

So, I have a file that has been changed locally:

```
(dev) go|c:\srv\lib\core\dknorway> git status
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   dknorway/data/postnrdata.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I want to revert the local changes (and pull down the correct version):

```
(dev) go|c:\srv\lib\core\dknorway> git checkout dknorway/data/postnrdata.txt
Updated 1 path from the index
```

I've tried adding the `--` and using windows path separators (`/`) with exactly the same results:

```
(dev) go|c:\srv\lib\core\dknorway> git status
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   dknorway/data/postnrdata.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

the file has become a zombie.. What have I done wrong?

**Update:** yes, there are two dknorway directories, one inside the other:

```
(dev) go|c:\srv\lib\core\dknorway> dir dknorway\data
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 04D6-81F0

 Directory of c:\srv\lib\core\dknorway\dknorway\data

2019-11-17  21:24    <DIR>          .
2019-11-17  21:24    <DIR>          ..
2019-11-17  21:24           150,705 postnrdata.txt
               1 File(s)        150,705 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  202,736,001,024 bytes free

(dev) go|c:\srv\lib\core\dknorway>
```

Comment: So do you have the folder structure `c:\srv\lib\core\dknorway\dknorway\data\postnrdata.txt` with two `dknorway` levels? You're probably just one level too deep, try `git checkout -- data/postnrdata.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that you are in c:\srv\lib\core\dknorway.  If the path to the file is c:\srv\lib\core\dknorway\data\postnrdata.txt then you need to go down a directory to c:\srv\lib\core

This should work providing that you are in the right directory.

```
git checkout -- dknorway/data/postnrdata.txt
```

If there are no other changes, then you can do the following to revert all changes

```
git reset --hard
```

Or you can use the stash

```
git stash
git stash drop
```